# What does 「諜づかいがオタナリ」 mean?

Tags: meaning, words, slang

I came across this sentence as a bullet point on a manga character's info sheet. I think it may be alternatively written 「諜使いがヲタナリ」 since I gather 「ヲタナリ」 means something like “otaku wannabe”, is that correct?

Comment: Do you have the original picture?

Comment: まさか「言葉づかいがキタナい」なんてことはないですよね・・

Comment: Almost certainly you have misread something. オタナリ/ヲタナリ is not a word which ordinary otaku are familiar with.

Comment: Yes I did misread it, thanks for the help – I'll upvote you and mark the answer as accepted once I have enough rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I misread the handwriting -- I'm pretty sure @chocolate's suggestion of 「言葉づかいがキタナい」 is correct, meaning that the character is foul-mouthed.

Answer (score 0):

言葉使いがヲタなり。

- His language is Otaku-ish.
- His speech-pattern is echt Otaku. -- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/echt

なり。 is an old-fashioned form of the -DA ending.